# Chart.JS Get the Y Axis value based on the X axis value

Tags: vue.js, charts, chart.js

Need some guidance. I have a chart which is displaying tide times throughout the day.

What I need to do is mark on the curve the height (Y Axis) based on the current time of day:

e.g. If the time was 14:00

[image]

Here is my code:

```
const chart = new Chart(this.$refs.myChart, {
                    type: "line",
                    data: {
                        labels,
                        datasets: [
                            {
                                data,
                                tension: 0.5,
                                backgroundColor: "rgb(31,89,112,0.5)",
                                borderColor: "rgb(31,89,112,1)",
                                fill: {
                                    target: "origin",
                                },
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                    options: {
                        interaction: {
                            mode: "point",
                        },
                        hover: {
                            mode: "point",
                        },
                        onHover: (e) => {
                            const canvasPosition = getRelativePosition(e, chart);

                            // Substitute the appropriate scale IDs
                            const dataX = chart.scales.xAxis.getValueForPixel(
                                canvasPosition.x
                            );
                            const dataY = chart.scales.yAxis.getValueForPixel(
                                canvasPosition.y
                            );
                            // console.log(dataY);
                        },
                        plugins: {
                            tooltip: {
                                enabled: true,
                                callbacks: {
                                    label: function(context) {
                                        var label = context.dataset.label || "";

                                        if (label) {
                                            label += ": ";
                                        }
                                        if (context.parsed.y !== null) {
                                            label += context.parsed.y + "m";
                                        }
                                        return label;
                                    },
                                },
                            },
                            legend: {
                                display: false,
                            },
                        },
                        scales: {
                            xAxis: {
                                type: "time",
                                min: new Date(date), // Should calculate this dynamic, not best way but can use: new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0)
                                max: new Date(date + (86400000 - 1000)),
                                time: {
                                    unit: "hour",
                                    stepSize: 2,
                                    displayFormats: {
                                        hour: "HH:mm",
                                    },

                                    // minUnit: moment(1634860800000).format("HH:mm"),
                                },
                                ticks: {
                                    major: true,
                                },
                            },
                            yAxis: {
                                ticks: {
                                    callback: function(value, index, values) {
                                        return value + "m";
                                    },
                                },
                            },
                        },
                    },
                });
```

Any ideas how I can achieve the red dot. I have tried addeding a second dataset however this doesnt follow the curve (As the curve is generated by `tension: 0.5`)?

Thanks in advance!

***Edit***
Here is a sample of what would be in var data and var labels

```
var labels = [
'2021-11-04T05:26:52.5',
'2021-11-04T11:21:06.667',
'2021-11-04T17:55:52.5',
'2021-11-04T23:47:30',
'2021-11-05T06:11:37.5'
]; // Times

var data = [
0.9,
5.3,
0.4,
5.4,
0.8
]; // Heights
```

Comment: did you try adding the same tension to the second dataset?

Comment: Yes but no luck. Problem is that it's it's just a single data in dataset 2. Dataset 1 is tide height data over 24 hours of the current date. What I want to do is mark on the line the point which corresponds to the time that they are viewing the chart, so the can see the height of the tide. This point might between 2 points on dataset 1.

Comment: will you please share a sample of the data used for dataset 1? above: `labels` & `data`

Comment: Hi @WhiteHat. I have edited the question to include a sample at the bottom. Thanks for your help in advance!